# Python Crypto - example script explanation

Tags: python

I've been trying to work out why the below code is failing to pad the IV with 16bytes. I've taken a look at the Crypto docs but I am none the wiser. I have found a few examples online but I don’t see the failing difference in the code below and the working examples (in Ruby). Any help would be appreciated.

```
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from base64 import b64decode

key = """
4e 99 06 e8  fc b6 6c c9  fa f4 93 10  62 0f fe e8
f4 96 e8 06  cc 05 79 90  20 9b 09 a4  33 b6 6c 1b
"""
key.replace(" ","").replace("\n","").decode('hex')

password1 = "j1Uyj3Vx8TY9LtLZil2uAuZkFQA/4latT76ZwgdHdhw"
password1 += "=" * ((4 - len(password1) % 4) % 4)
password = b64decode(password1)

o = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC).decrypt(password)

print o[:-ord(o[-1])].decode('utf16')
```

Comment: To note: `str.replace` returns a *new* string - it doesn't modify the existing string... so `key = key.replace(...)`

Comment: Thanks Jon, im still getting the error `ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

def rpad(s, fill='=', multiple=8):
    """
    Pad s with the fill char so the length of the string 
    is a multiple of `multiple` (default 8).
    """
    return s + fill * (-len(s) % multiple)

key = """
4e 99 06 e8  fc b6 6c c9  fa f4 93 10  62 0f fe e8
f4 96 e8 06  cc 05 79 90  20 9b 09 a4  33 b6 6c 1b
"""
key = key.replace(" ","").replace("\n","").decode('hex')

mode = AES.MODE_CBC
iv = "\x00"*16
enc = AES.new(key, mode, iv)

password = "j1Uyj3Vx8TY9LtLZil2uAuZkFQA/4latT76ZwgdHdhw"
decoded = base64.b64decode(rpad(password, multiple=4))

o = enc.decrypt(decoded)
print(o[:-ord(o[-1])].decode('utf16'))
```

prints

```
Local*P4ssword!
```

---

- As Jon Clements pointed out, `key.replace(...)` returns a string. You need to reassign that string
  to `key`, or else the replacement is done for naught.

Comment: I just copied the above exactly and am still getting the same error :$

Comment: @ubuntu  Im still getting `ValueError: IV must be 16 bytes long`

Comment: I think perhaps the reason for the ValueError is due [this change in the API](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pycrypto/+bug/1018283). The initialization string, `iv`, is no longer optional. I've modified the code to add an explicity `iv`.

Comment: I am now getting a result. Could you explain what your rpad function is doing?

Comment: `rpad` pads the string with equal signs on the right so the resulting string has a length which is a multiple of 4. It's purpose is the same as `password1 += "=" * ((4 - len(password1) % 4) % 4)`. You need to pad the string because b64decode expects its input to have a length which is a multiple of 4. Since there are other situations where I have use for this utility, I made it a helper function.

Comment: Awesome thanks unutbu. Could you break down the `password1 += "=" * ((4 - len(password1) % 4) % 4)` line or point me at a link that could help explain it. Id like to understand it, I understand the rest of the code (except the final print) but im not sure how this is achieving what it is achieving.

Comment: I'd be glad to help you, but first, please break your question into smaller, more pointed questions. What part are you curious about? What symbols do you not understand? Make a list, ask one question, and we'll iterate through the list.

Comment: Did you want me to ask a "new question" asking to explain what this `password1 += "=" * ((4 - len(password1) % 4) % 4)` is doing?.

Comment: That's fine. But note if you ask a question of the form, "Explain this" it may
not be well received because there is too great a disparity between the effort
it takes to ask the question and the effort it takes to answer it. You can help
bridge that gap by stating the parts you already understand, what you've tried
to resolve the question, by linking to the the docs you've researched and by
asking a targeted question that has a short answer (like "what does XYZ do in
this piece of code. I tried this experiment but don't see the
pattern"). Remember, you can ask multiple questions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your issue, but you may have a typo. :) `password2` should read `password1` I  think.

Comment: @iNoob In your `b64decode()` line you're still referencing `password2`.

Comment: apologies forgot to change the second ref to it :)